# How to scrape a table with changing data using Cheerio in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, cheerio, request-promise

I am trying to **scrape data from a table in a website which has constantly changing values**. So each row can vary day to day but I want to be able to scrape the correct data. I am using the Cheerio library at the moment and I am not familiar with it but here's what I have:

```
const rp = require("request-promise");
const cheerio = require("cheerio");

let Italy = "";

async function main() {
    const result = await rp.get("https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/");
    const $ = cheerio.load(result);

    $("#main_table_countries > tbody:nth-child(2) > tr:nth-child(2)").each((i,el) => {
        const item = $(el).text();
        Italy = item;
    });
}
```

So, as you can see this scrapes data from the worldometer website for the coronavirus cases in Italy. Italy's position however has been changing between 2 and 3 over the past few days. This has resulted in my program fetching the wrong information. This is what I would like to fix.

Here's the link to the worldometer website:
https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/

Thanks,
Karthik

Comment: You might not need to scrape HTML at all: see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60583372/how-to-parse-csv-from-github/60583614#60583614) about getting live Coronavirus data from CSV, which lead to this: https://jsfiddle.net/jys01z9b/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I Implemented is that you can get all the `tr's` and loop over them to get all the names and add it to an array and then use the Array Index to find any country you want

```
async function main() {
    let NamesArr=[]
    let CountryToFind= 'Italy'


    const result = await rp.get("https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/");
    const $ = cheerio.load(result);

    $('#main_table_countries').find('tbody').eq(0).find('tr').each((i,el)=>{
        NamesArr.push($(el).find('td').eq(0).text().trim())
    })

    let Index= NamesArr.indexOf(CountryToFind) + 1 

    $(`#main_table_countries > tbody:nth-child(2) > tr:nth-child(${Index})`).each((i,el) => {
        const item = $(el).text();
        console.log(item);
    });
}

main()
```

This Returns me

[image: CMD Result Image]

You can definitely refactor it but this way makes your parser dynamic as you can now search for any country.

Answer (score 1):

Use the :contains pseudo for this:

```
$('tr:contains(Italy)').text()
//"  Italy  9,172   +1,797   463  +97  724    7,985  733   151.7 "
```